# Tengo una falla en mi sintaxis en el código de mi buscador en tiempo real

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo un buscador en tiempo que real, que dependiendo lo que el usuario elija desde una lista de `select` el buscador filtra los resultados. El tema es que filtra todo bien, pero un `select` específico entre los 4 que hay falla, es el `select` con id="precio". No salta ningún error en mi página, simplemente no filtra, así que asumo que algo está mal en mi código. Tengo 3 páginas. La primera con los select, la segunda con el js, y la tercera con el php que busca en la base de datos. Les dejo mi código a ver si logran ver la falla.

Primera página con los select

```
  <select name="precio" id="precio">
    <option value="">Precios</option>
    <option value="1" data-min=3000 data-max=11000>3000-11000</option>
    <option value="2" data-min=11000 data-max=22000>11000-22000</option>
  </select>
<!---Considero innecesario mostrar los otros select, solo falla este----->
```

Página con el js

```
inicio();
function inicio() {
    resultados();
}


function resultados(pais,marca,categoria,precio_min,precio_max){

$.ajax({
   url : 'buscando.php',
     type : 'POST',
     datatype :'html',
   data : {
         pais: pais,
                 marca : marca,
                 categoria : categoria,
                 preciomin : precio_min,
                 preciomax : precio_max
     },
})

.done(function(resultado) {
    $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
})

}


function busqueda(){
    var pais=$("#paises").val();
    var marca=$("#marca").val();
    var categoria=$("#categoria").val();
    var precio_min=$("#precio").find('selectd').data("min");
    var precio_max=$("#precio").find('selectd').data("max");
    resultados(pais,marca,categoria,precio_min,precio_max);
}


<!---Hay uno de estos para cada select, pero considero innecesario mostrarlos------>
$(document).on('change','#precio', function() {
     busqueda();
});
```

Y por último el php que busca

```
$p_min="";
$p_max="";

$query = "SELECT
                    p.id,
                    p.descri,
                    p.precio,
                    m.nombre_m,
                    c.nombre_c,
                    p.pais,
                    p.imagen
            FROM productos p
            INNER JOIN marcas m     ON p.marca  = m.id
            INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.catego = c.id
            WHERE p.pais LIKE '%".$p."%'
                  AND p.marca LIKE '%".$m."%'
                        AND p.catego LIKE '%".$c."%'
            ";


            if(isset($_POST['precio_min'])) {
                $p_min=$_POST['precio_min'];
                $p_max =$_POST['precio_max'];
                $query = $query." AND p.precio BETWEEN ".$p_min." AND ".$p_max;
            }

    $buscarreg=$conexion->query($query);
    if ($buscarreg->num_rows > 0){
        $tabla.=
        "<table class='table'>
            <tr class='bg-primary'>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Precio</td>
                    <td>Imagen</td>
                    <td>País</td>
                    <td>Marca</td>
                    <td>Categoría</td>
                    <td>Descripción</td>
            </tr>";
        while($filareg= $buscarreg->fetch_assoc()){
            $imagen = $filareg['imagen'];
            $tabla.= '<tr>
                <td>'.$filareg['id'].'</td>
                <td>'.utf8_encode($filareg['precio']).'</td>
                <td><img src='.$imagen.' width="50" height="50"></td>
                <td>'.utf8_encode($filareg['pais']).'</td>
                <td>'.utf8_encode($filareg['nombre_m']).'</td>
                <td>'.utf8_encode($filareg['nombre_c']).'</td>
                <td>'.utf8_encode($filareg['descri']).'</td>
             </tr>
            ';
        }
        $tabla.='</table>';
        echo "Resultados";
        echo $tabla;
    }
```

Comment: de donde se supone que viene precio_min?

Comment: del select con id=precio. ahí está data-min y data-max. Luego en una de las funciones del js digo que precio_min=$("#precio").find('selectd').data("min"); lo mismo con el "max".

Comment: pero no esta viajando eso.. en el data pusiste preciomin : precio_min.. o sea, viaja preciomin?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo hubieras escrito tú para que funcione?

Comment: como quieras, lo que pregunto es si en el data que estas mandando al post, viaja precio_min o preciomin.. que son dos cosas distintas ;)

Comment: Creo que precio_min. si te referís a esto claro ($_POST['precio_min'])). Aunque creo que te estás refiriendo a otra cosa....

Comment: data : {......,preciomin : precio_min, preciomax : precio_max }, cual es el nombre de la variable que viaja? preciomin o precio_min? y cual estas esperando vos????

Comment: Eso no se puede ver en el código que mostré? (Es la primera vez que hago un buscador así y no entiendo mucho)

Comment: Trataba de que entendieras tu codigo.. tu php espera precio_min como nombre de parametro, pero estas mandando preciomin como nombre de parametro... ahora lo entendes?

Comment: y cómo lo mando como precio_min?

Comment: cambiando el nombre en el data?... ;)

Comment: Algo así?  var data-min=$("#precio").find('selectd').data("min");

 resultados(pais,marca,categoria,data-min,data-max);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto mandas en tu data:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'buscando.php',
    type : 'POST',
    datatype :'html',
    data : {
            pais: pais,
            marca : marca,
            categoria : categoria,
            preciomin : precio_min,
            preciomax : precio_max
    },
})
```

ahi mandas una propiedad que dice preciomin (para max es lo mismo)..

tu php, luego busca lo siguiente:

```
if(isset($_POST['precio_min'])) {
```

y no, no existe precio_min, porque en tu data viaja preciomin...

dos opciones, o cambias tu data

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'buscando.php',
    type : 'POST',
    datatype :'html',
    data : {
            pais: pais,
            marca : marca,
            categoria : categoria,
            precio_min: precio_min,
            precio_max : precio_max
    },
})
```

o cambias tu php

```
if(isset($_POST['preciomin'])) {
    $p_min=$_POST['preciomin'];
    $p_max =$_POST['preciomax'];
```

Comment: Sí, luego me había dado cuenta de eso, y lo cambié, pero sigue sin salirme resultados a la hora de seleccionar precio

Comment: @Andres90tl y para eso deberiamos ver como queda tu query y los datos en tu tabla.. y ver si tu query esta bien formado o no...

Comment: Yo muestro ese código en mi pregunta

Comment: @Andres90tl como queda, cual es el query que realmente esta ejecutando, y ver si ese query tiene datos en la db..

Comment: Al final lo hice de otra forma. Según el número del input, elijo cuánto vale el min y el max. Del otro método no sé por qué pero no me llegaba el dato.